# How to escape single quotation at easyui form load

Tags: javascript, html

I encountered a quite few data values (e.g person's name) that contains ' char in the mid of string causing binding error. I've tried few escape method like `name:escape(jsonStr.name)`, but it isn't helping solve the problem. Could it be a speicfic issue for easyui components or i didn't step on right stone?

Answer (score 0):

To escape the single quotes, you could replace all single quotes `'` with a backslash, followed by a single quote `\'`.

Comment: Hi, I did replace at backend. Would it be better do it in js after eval(str), some like str.replace("'", "\'")?